# How to pass a volatile parameter to a Java method in a different class?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

**I know Java is PASS-BY-VALUE. But how can I achieve this goal of passing the reference?**

ClassA contains a volatile variable

```
public class ClassA extends QuartzJobBean implements InterruptableJob {
    private volatile boolean isInterrupted = false; 

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) 
            throws JobExecutionException { 
        new ClassB().callNewMethod(isInterrupted); 
        //I want callNewMethod get the REFERENCE and not the VALUE of isInterrupted 
    } 

    @Override
    public void interrupt() throws UnableToInterruptJobException {
        isInterrupted = true;
    } 
}
```

---

ClassB contains worker methods

```
public class ClassB {

    protected void callNewMethod(boolean isInterrupted)   { 
        stepOne();  
        if (!isInterrupted) { 
            stepTwo(); 
        }
        if (!isInterrupted) { 
            stepThree(); 
        }
        if (!isInterrupted) { 
            stepFour(); 
        }
    } 
}
```

I tried synchronized, but that doesn't work since each thread need to have it's own volatile `isInterrupted` reference

Comment: Why is your code not formatted but rather all left-justified? Why make it harder to read then necessary?

Comment: Sounds like you need/want a call-back/listener scheme

Comment: Try `AtomicBoolean` instead of `volatile boolean`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels looks more like an attempt to create background job responsive to interruption

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Formatting applied . Thank you

Comment: @Ivan thank you so much. AtomicBoolean works for me